# Writing modules in Haskell the right way

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, separation-of-concerns, decoupling, design-principles

(I'm totally rewriting this question to give it a better focus; you can see the history of changes if you want to see the original.)

Let's say I have two modules:

- One module defines the function `inverseAndSqrt`. What this function actually does is not important; what is important is that it returns none, one, or both of two things in a way that the client can distinguish which one is which;

```hs
module Module1 (inverseAndSqrt) where

type TwoOpts a = (Maybe a, Maybe a)

inverseAndSqrt :: Int -> TwoOpts Float
inverseAndSqrt x = (if x /= 0 then Just (1.0/(fromIntegral x)) else Nothing,
                    if x >= 0 then Just (sqrt $ fromIntegral x) else Nothing)
```

- another module defines other functions depending on `inverseAndSqrt` and on its type

```hs
module Module2 where

import Module1

fun :: (Maybe Float, Maybe Float) -> Float
fun (Just x, Just y) = x + y
fun (Just x, Nothing) = x
fun (Nothing, Just y) = y

exportedFun :: Int -> Float
exportedFun = fun . inverseAndSqrt
```

What I want to understand from the perspective of design principle is: how should I interface `Module1` with other modules (e.g. `Module2`) in a way that makes it well encapsulated, reusable, etc?

The problems I see are

- I could one day decide that I don't want to use a pair to return the two results anymore; I could decide to use a 2 elements list; or another type which is isomorphic (I think this is the right adjective, isn't it?) to a pair; if I do this, all client code will break
- Exporting the `TwoOpts` type synonym doesn't solve anything, as `Module1` could still change its implementation thus breaking client code.
- `Module1` is also forcing the type of the two optionals to be the same, but I'm not sure this is really relevant to this question...

How should I design `Module1` (and thus edit `Module2` as well) such that the two are not tightly coupled?

One thing I can think of is that maybe I should define a type`class` expressing what "a box with two optional things in it" is, and then `Module1` and `Module2` would use that as a common interface. But should that be in both module? In either of them? Or in none of them, in a third module? Or maybe such a `class`/concept is not needed?

I'm not a computer scientist so I'm sure that this question highlights some misunderstanding of mine due to lack of experience *and* theoretical background. Any help filling the gaps is welcome.

### Possible modifications I'd like to support

- Related to what chepner suggested in a comment to his answer, at some point I might want to extend the support from 2-tuple things to both 2- and 3-tuple things, having different accessor names for them, suche as `get1of2`/`get2of2` (let's say these are the name we use when we first design `Module1`) vs `get1of3`/`get2of3`/`get3of3`.
- At some point I would also be able to complement this 2-tuple-like type with something else, for instance an optional containing `Just` the sum¹ of the two main contents only if they are both `Just`s, or a `Nothing` if at least one of the two main contents is a `Nothing`. I guess in this case the internal representation of this class would be something like `((Maybe a, Maybe a), Maybe b)` (¹ The sum is really a stupid example, so I've used `b` here instead of `a` to be more general than the sum would require).

Comment: Some change is always going to break your API. Just pick a simple one (like that) and don’t worry about it.

Comment: @Ry-, I agree that there will always be _some_ change that breaks the API; but I guess that making the chance this happes more unlikely or, in other words, reducing the set of possible changes that can break the API is a good thing, don't you agree?

Comment: just wanted to point out that your result type is isomorphic to [Data.These](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.1.1.1), although in your case I might actually opt to use `(Maybe a, Maybe a)`. When you have an `x :: These a a`, it’s unclear which of the constructors (`This` or `That`) corresponds to the first possibility because the constructors can’t be disambiguated by their type.

Comment: @Enrico: If it’s worth it and I can think of a useful change it would allow. This doesn’t look like an example of a case where it’s worth it. I would think about the API and make a choice of type, then avoid breaking it without good reason. For this type of function, I would choose between `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` and a `newtype MeaningfulName a = MeaningfulName { mnInverse :: Maybe a, mnSqrt :: Maybe a }`.  A list is not a good choice because it has many invalid values, so this representation is unlikely to change without changing the meaning of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define a simple type alias; this exposes the details of how you implement `TwoOpts`.

Instead, define a new type, but *don't* export the data constructor, but rather functions for accessing the two components. Then you are free to change the implementation of the type all you like without changing the interface, because the user can't pattern-match on a value of type `TwoOpts a`.

```
module Module1 (TwoOpts, inverseAndSqrt, getFirstOpt, getSecondOpt) where

data TwoOpts a = TwoOpts (Maybe a) (Maybe a)

getFirstOpt, getSecondOpt :: TwoOpts a -> Maybe a
getFirstOpt (TwoOpts a _) = a
getSecondOpt (TwoOpts _ b) = b

inverseAndSqrt :: Int -> TwoOpts Float
inverseAndSqrt x = TwoOpts (safeInverse x) (safeSqrt x)
    where safeInverse 0 = Nothing
          safeInverse x = Just (1.0 / fromIntegral x)
          safeSqrt x | x >= 0 = Just $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x
                     | otherwise = Nothing
```

and

```
module Module2 where

import Module1

fun :: TwoOpts Float -> Float
fun a = case (getFirstOpts a, getSecondOpt a) of
          (Just x, Just y) -> x + y
          (Just x, Nothing) -> x
          (Nothing, Just y) -> y

exportedFun :: Int -> Float
exportedFun = fun . inverseAndSqrt
```

---

Later, when you realize that you've reimplemented the type product, you can change your definitions without affecting any user code.

```
newtype TwoOpts a = TwoOpts { getOpts :: (Maybe a, Maybe a) }

getFirstOpt, getSecondOpt :: TwoOpts a -> Maybe a
getFirstOpt  = fst . getOpts
getSecondOpt = snd . getOpts
```

Comment: You explained why using `type` would be "wrong"; so the alternative is either `data` or `newtype`, and we use the former in the initial scenario when we haven't relized yet [...], so we need the full power of `data` as there's no type we can start from; in the second scenario, realized we are ok with a pair, we don't need to use `data` anymore, since `newtype` is enough. Is this correct?

Comment: Right. It's not clear you would really want to use anything other than the two implementations I show above, but it's possible that `TwoOpts` might, for example, actually become a container for *three* (or more) possibly non-existent values (making `TwoOpts` a bit of a misnomer). You could then define, say, `newtype TwoOpts a = TwoOpts (Maybe a) (Maybe a) (Maybe a)`, and simply *add* `getThirdOpt` to the list of functions exported by the module. Again, code that isn't concerned with the new additions wouldn't need to change at all.

Comment: The extension to 3 is exactly one of the possible changes I have in mind. Please, give a look at the update to my question. Maybe you have some meaningful extension to you answer to address that?

Comment: I have another question too. `inverseAndSqrt` connot live out of `Module1` because it has to construct a `TwoOpts`, and it couldn't from the outside, as `Module1` is not exporting the constructor. Nor we would like to export the costructor (as you say for `type`, also the ctor would expose details). So if I want to factor `inverseAndSqrt` out of `Module1` I should make `Module1` export a function which constructs the object? How do you see this?

Comment: It's almost trivially simple: `buildTwoOpts = TwoOpts`. The difference is that you can't use `buildTwoOpts` to pattern-match on a value.

Answer (score 3):

To me, Haskell design is all type-centric.  The design rule for functions is just "use the most general and accurate types that do the job", and the whole problem of design in Haskell is about coming up with the best types for the job.

We would like there to be no "junk" in the types, so that they have exactly one representation for each value you want to denote.  E.g. `String` is a bad representation for numbers, because `"0", "0.0", "-0"` all mean the same thing, and also because `"The Prisoner"` is not a number -- it is a valid representation that does not have a valid denotation.   If, say for performance reasons, the same denotation can be represented multiple ways, the type's API should make that difference invisible to the user.

So in your case, `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` is perfect -- it means exactly what you need it to mean.  Using something more complicated is unnecessary, and will just complicate matters for the user.  At some point whatever you expose will have to be convertible to a `Maybe a` for the first thing and a `Maybe a` for the second thing, and there is no extra information than that, so the tuple is perfect.  Whether you use a type synonym or not is a matter of style -- I prefer not use synonyms at all and only give types names when I have a more formal abstraction in mind.

Connotation is important.  For example, if I had a function for finding the roots of a quadratic polynomial, I probably wouldn't use `TwoOpts`, even though there are at most two of them.  The fact that my return values are all "the same kind of thing" in an intuitive sense makes me prefer a list (or if I'm feeling particularly picky, a `Set` or `Bag`), even if the list has at most two elements.  I just have it match my best understanding of the domain at the time, so I won't change it unless my understanding of the domain has changed in a significant way, in which case the opportunity to review all its uses is exactly what I want.  If you are writing your functions to be as polymorphic as possible, then often you won't need to change anything but the specific moments the meaning is used, the exact moment domain knowledge is required (such as understanding the relationship between `TwoOpts` and `Set`). You don't need to "redo the plumbing" if it's made of a sufficiently flexible, polymorphic material.

Supposing you didn't have a clean isomorphism to a standard type like `(Maybe a, Maybe a)`, and you wanted to formalize `TwoOpts`.  The way here is to build an API out of its constructors, combinators, and eliminators.  For example:

```
data TwoOpts a    -- abstract, not exposed

-- constructors 
none :: TwoOpts a
justLeft :: a -> TwoOpts a
justRight :: a -> TwoOpts a
both :: a -> a -> TwoOpts a

-- combinators
-- Semigroup and Monoid at least
swap :: TwoOpts a -> TwoOpts a

-- eliminators
getLeft :: TwoOpts a -> Maybe a
getRight :: TwoOpts a -> Maybe a
```

In this case the eliminators give exactly your representation `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` as their final coalgebra.

```
-- same as the tuple in a newtype, just more conventional
data TwoOpts a = TwoOpts (Maybe a) (Maybe a)
```

Or if you wanted to focus on the constructors side you could use an initial algebra

```
data TwoOpts a
    = None
    | JustLeft a
    | JustRight a
    | Both a a
```

You are at liberty to change this representation as long as it still implements the combinatory API above.  If you have reason to use different representations of the same API, make the API into a typeclass (typeclass design is a whole other story).

In Einstein's famous words, "make it as simple as possible, but no simpler".

Comment: I agree on the first paragraph, but I still don't have the "programming maturity" to be able to forsee what is the perfect type. For instance, at the beginning `(Maybe a, Maybe a)` might seem perfect (to me too), but I can think of a case where once I know they are both `Just`s, I want to provide some more information that relates the two. And that should end up in the type too, no? I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Enrico, Yes.  Design-wise I would say you should choose your own best understanding of the domain at the time (so I'm speaking of a subjective rather than objective perfection). If you want to include this extra information, change the type at the moment you know enough about said information to choose the right type to replace it with -- i.e. I wouldn't design around the *possibility* of *maybe someday* changing it to some unknown future thing, because I am probably wrong about what shape it will take anyway and just making things complicated for myself in the meantime.

Comment: @Enrico, oh, I see your update.  In this case, you do have some concrete future plans for what you would like to do.  I would say don't worry about designing it to be flexible for such changes -- either write it the simple way knowing you will have to change it someday, or write it the right way up front (maybe eliding the implementation of some functionality you don't yet need).  There are too many "unknown unknowns" to properly encode your own uncertainty.  Get clear.